# Is it possible it integrate VBA scripting with C++ in order to invoke function calls?

Tags: c++, vba, api, excel

I want to link VBA scripting for excel with C++ in order to invoke functions between the environments? Is this possible??

Comment: Yes I think so [See this](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/integrate-c-program-into-vba.80/)

Comment: You can do this via Excels built in COM Automation features, this exposes Macros/VBA projects in a workbook, MSDN: [Office Automation Using Visual C++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196776)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you have an automation-compatible COM api, use that.

If you have a simple handle-based API, you can use VBA's external function declaration syntax.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243324(v=vs.60).aspx

Or, you can write a type library for the API, using `midl`.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367091(v=vs.85).aspx

Or, you can use C++ to write a COM or handle-based wrapper around the C++ API.